# VB6, ActiveReports, and CanGrow property

Tags: vb6, textbox, runtime, size, activereports

I've got an ActiveReport which has a textbox populated at run time. The "cangrow" and "multiline" properties are both set to "true".

When I run the report on my machine, the report prints out fine with all of the text set at run time. IE: "Dear John, hello -- how are you..." There's only about 250 characters for this textbox.

However, one of the machines downstairs will only print the name of the textbox. IE: "txtVerbage". A blank report with "txtVerbage" in the middle of it, where the body (see above) should be.

Has anyone else had this experience? I've been banging my head against the wall for days now.

Thanks,

Jason

Comment: First, perhaps add some source code to your question that shows how you populate the field. Second, it would be interesting to know what the TextBox's contents are before you set them. Third, are there any possible causes you can rule out? Lastly, what version of ActiveReports are you using? Are you using the same version on both machines? Have you already checked DataDynamics' forums? Are there any bugfixes you might install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its probably the timing of when you're setting the Field/TextBox value. Make sure you set it in the Format event of the section containing the control (e.g. Detail_Format). Using the BeforePrint or AfterPrint or one of the Report events can yield unpredictable results like this.

Also be sure you set the Field.DataValue property and not the Text property.

Some background information on this is in the articles below:

- [ActiveReports Architecture: Report Processing](http://www.datadynamics.com/Help/AR2Std/HX_Report_Processing.html)
- [ActiveReports Architecture: Events](http://www.datadynamics.com/Help/AR2Std/HX_Events.html)
- [Navigable documentation w/ TOC](http://www.datadynamics.com/Help/AR2Std/AR2Std_start.htm)

Hope this helps!

```
 Scott Willeke
 GrapeCity
```

Comment: If the report is not bound, don't think he'll get any ot the `Detail` events.

Comment: Thanks for the note, but as long as you use the DataInitialize/FetchData events to do "unbound mode" events will fire just as if it is bound to a data source. More about using unbound mode in AR2: http://www.datadynamics.com/Help/AR2Std/HX_Simple_Unbound_Reports.html

Answer (score 0):

The data you access from downstairs is not there.  That is why when you bind the data to the report, nothing appears.  The reason you see txtVerbage is because that is what you called the text control and that was the default text there.

So you need to make sure that you are actually getting data.

Comment: It's not a bound control. The value is assigned txtVerbage = "the real literal string is much, much bigger than this". But thanks, anyways!

Comment: So you are probably skipping this assignment, probably because of unhandled error just before it... where is my crystal ball.